# Travel outside Pakistan

Tags: passports, standard-visitor-visas

I want to travel to UK from Pakistan for 15 days  and I have valid visa but my passport will expire in 3 months.

Will I have any issues at Pakistan airport at the departure time? I check from gov.uk and I can enter UK as long as my return flight is few months before passport expiry.

Comment: What is your citizenship and residence status in the UK (if you are not a UK citizen)?

Comment: Is the "valid visa" a visa issued by the UK?